# Sinatra REST server: How to Access 0.0.0.0:4567

Tags: rest, server, sinatra

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34631278/how-do-i-go-about-setting-up-my-sinatra-rest-api-on-a-server) question is almost what I need, but I'm looking for the next step.

I have a simple Ruby app using Sinatra running on a school server as follows:

```
== Sinatra (v1.4.7) has taken the stage on 4567 for production with backup from Thin
Thin web server (v1.6.4 codename Gob Bluth)
Maximum connections set to 1024
Listening on 0.0.0.0:4567, CTRL+C to stop
```

Other web projects I run on the server (basic HTML/ Javascript) I can access through http://school_site/my_account/project_file.html etc.

What URL or IP address do I use for requests to the API?

I have tried all combinations of /my_account/project_file:4567/ and tried the IP address on the server I found using /sbin/iconfig with :4567 but I haven't had any luck.

I'm testing using POSTMAN.

Any guidance is much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: server IP address should have worked, but maybe there is a firewall in the way. Check with the school's network admin how the server can be accessed remotely (from the school network or publicly).

Comment: @Thilo, thank you. Its good to know I was on the right track. I will check with the school.